# Hacer pivot a una tabla con un cursoren sql server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, pivot, cursor

Cordial saludo.

Lo que deseo hacer es un cursor que me permita hacer pivot a una tabla, lo he intentado pero no me funciona.

Esta es la tabla que deseo pivotear:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código para crear la tabla e insertar los datos:

```
   CREATE TABLE TABLA_1 (
          TERMINAL VARCHAR(MAX),
          TEXT_NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
          CONTENT VARCHAR(MAX)
   );
```

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('34','ID RAN','2');
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('34','NOMBRE RAN','PORT_L');
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('34','NOMBRE RAN','LOR_P');
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('56','ID RAN','5');
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('56','NOMBRE RAN','PROMPT');
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('78','ID RAN','5');
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('78','ID AS','9');
INSERT INTO TABLA_1 (TERMINAL,TEXT_NAME,CONTENT) VALUES('88','POL_L','DEFINIDO');
```

y este es el resultado que espero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe aclarar que estos datos son de ejemplo, solo quiero saber si se puede dar vuelta a una tabla con un cursor y si la respuesta es sí, quisiera saber como. Estoy empezando con sql server.

Agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Poder, claro que se puede, pero salvo el sentido didáctico del uso de cursores, en TSQL, hacerlo como dices, no lo tiene.

```
--- Variable de tabla para salida
Declare @Vartablesalida Table
                              (
                              terminal VarChar(Max)
                            , ran1     VarChar(Max)
                            , nombre   VarChar(Max)
                            , ran2     VarChar(Max)
                            , idas     VarChar(Max)
                            , pol      VarChar(Max)
                              );

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Declaración de variables que recogen los valores de la query del cursor
DECLARE @TerminalValue varchar(max);
Declare @TextNameValue varchar(max);
Declare @ContentValue varchar(max);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- Declaración del cursor
DECLARE miCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT TERMINAL, TEXT_NAME, CONTENT
FROM dbo.TABLA_1;

--- Apertura del cursor
OPEN miCursor
--- Datos a variables.
 FETCH NEXT FROM miCursor INTO @TerminalValue, @TextNameValue,@ContentValue
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 --bucle
BEGIN
    -- Trabajamos con las variables los datos a obtener

    Insert into @varTableSalida (TERMINAL, ran1, Nombre, ran2, idas, pol)
    values (
        @TerminalValue, -- 1ª COLUMNA
        case @TextNameValue when 'ID RAN' THEN @ContentValue ELSE '' END, --2ª COLUMNA
        case @TextNameValue when 'NOMBRE RAN' THEN @ContentValue ELSE '' END, --3ª COLUMNA
        '', -- 4ª COLUMNA
        case @TextNameValue when 'ID AS' THEN @ContentValue ELSE '' END, --5ª COLUMNA
        case @TextNameValue when 'POL_L' THEN @ContentValue ELSE '' END --6ª COLUMNA
        );
    
--- Datos a variables.
 FETCH NEXT FROM miCursor INTO @TerminalValue, @TextNameValue,@ContentValue
END --- fin de bucle

--- cierre de cursor
CLOSE miCursor
--- liberar recursos
Deallocate miCursor


Select t.terminal
     , t.ran1 As [id ran]
     , t.nombre As [nombre ran]
     , t.ran2 As [id ran]
     , t.idas As [id as]
     , t.pol As pol_l
       From @Vartablesalida As t;
```

Para el ejemplo, primero declaro una variable de tabla que contendrá los datos temporales que se irán insertando en cada vuelta del cursor. Luego las variables que contendrán los datos leídos de la tabla origen, fila por fila. Y posteriormente la declaración del cursor.

Una vez ya está todo preparado, abrimos el cursor e iniciamos el bucle, siempre que la query devuelva alguna fila.

Insertamos en la variable tipo tabla, los datos para presentar la fila. Utilizo una sentencia case para escoger en función de los valores que tenga la variable textNameValue.

Y se va llenando la variable de tabla conforme el cursor va alimentándose de filas

Luego cerramos el cursor y liberamos recursos (muy importante).

Y por último extraemos el resultado.

[image: Resultados]

[Cursores TSQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Nota**: Siempre que puedas, *evita los cursores*

Comment: EXCELENTE!!, funcionó perfectamente. Pero quisiera saber como sería ese cursor dinámico, es decir, que no tenga que escrbir las columnas estáticamente sino que el cursor los pinte automáticamente.

Comment: Desconozco que quiere decir hacer un cursor dinámico. Si quieres hacer un pivot dinámico, puedes seguir este artículo. [pivot dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/), aunque para hacer un pivot dínámico primero deberías de comprender como se hace uno estático [pivot estático](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/16/pivot-simple-como-hacer-y-entenderlo-paso-por-paso/)

Comment: A lo que me refiero, es que como se haría para poder colocar las columnas de forma dinámica, es decir, que en vez de colocarlas manualmnete al momento de crear la variable tipo table, estas se agreguen con un ALTER TABLE o algo que recorra las filas de TEXT_NAME y las vaya agregando como columnas en la variable tipo table en cada iteración.

Comment: Utilizar para nombres de columnas, tablas, etc, el contenido extraído de los datos, implica obligatoriamente, utilizar sentencias dinámicas. La utilización de código dinámico es más o menos compleja, y mi recomendación, es que la dejes para más adelante. En el anterior comentario, ya te puse un enlace a un pivot dinámico. Es exactamente lo mismo. Creas una variable, y la alimentas con lo que extraes de alguna tabla, y luego haces un exec sp_execute tu variable. Pero yo lo dejaría para cuando domines la parte estática.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es que sea dinámico, no necesitas un cursor, si realmente quieres
un "cursor dinámico", solo adapta el código:

```
DECLARE @columnas AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @scritp     AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @columnas = STUFF((select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(TEXT_NAME) 
                          from TABLA_1
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
                          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,''
                         )
set @scritp = 'select TERMINAL,' + @columnas + ' from 
            (  select TERMINAL, CONTENT, TEXT_NAME
                from TABLA_1
            ) data
            pivot 
            (
                max(CONTENT)
                for TEXT_NAME in (' + @columnas + ')
            )piv'
execute(@scritp)
```